# How to disable autostart and autonext in dailymotion player sdk

Tags: dailymotion-api

```
  <script src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player/xps50.js"></script>
<div id="my-dailymotion-player">My Player placeholder</div>
<script>
    dailymotion.createPlayer("my-dailymotion-player", {
        video: "xx",
         player: 'xxx',
        params: {
 
      mute: true,
 
        }
    })
    .then((player) => console.log(player))
    .catch((e) => console.error(e));
</script>
```

i want how disable autostart ,autonext like this .. and i want all parameters